# extracting filename with extension form URL

Tags: java

Let's say I have the following string

```
http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png
```

What would be the best way to extract b84.png from it? My program will be getting a list of image URLs and I want to extract the file name with its extension from each URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to create a `File` like this:

```
String url = "http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png";
URI uri = URI.create(url);
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
```

The `uri.getPath()` returns only the path portion of the url (i.e. removes the scheme, host, etc.) and produces this:

`/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png`

You can then use the created `File` object to extract the file name from the full path:

```
String fileName = f.getName();
System.out.println(fileName);
```

Output of print statement would be:
`b84.png`

However if you are not at all concerned by the input format of the url(s) then the substring answers are more terse. I figured I would offer an alternative. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String url = "http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png";
String fileName = url.subString(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] urlArray=yourUrlString.split("/");
String fileName=urlArray[urlArray.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, string lastIndexOf method is the best way to extract file name

```
String str = "http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png";
String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1,str.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
 String url = "http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/748/132/b84.png"
 url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
```

If you don't png instead of .png, just change the last line to this-

```
 url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method perfect for you

```
public String Name(String url){
        url=url.replace('\\', '/');
        return  url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1,url.length());
    }
```

this method returns any filename of any directory...whitout errors because convert the "\" to "/" so never will have problems with diferent directories